# Passing Custom Object to DLL via Method Call

Tags: c#, methods, namespaces

So I have a namespace:

```
namespace Main
{
  Class DoStuff
  {
    Code...

    var tableVars = new Dictionary<string, tableObject>();

    Code...

    string insertResponse = MyDLL.Insert(someString, tableVars, someString);

    Code../

  }
  public class tableObject
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Default { get; set; }
  }
}
```

And I have a second namespace:

```
namespace MyDLL
{
  public static string Insert(string table, Dictionary<string, tableObject> tableVars, string connection)
  {
    Code...
  }
}
```

In my first namespace, Main, I have a reference to the second namespace, MyDLL. How can I get the DLL to recognize my custom object without referencing my Main namespace (as this will cause circular referencing)?

I also tried using the var keyword, but it doesn't work in this case:

```
namespace MyDLL
    {
      public static string Insert(string table, var tableVars, string connection)
      {
        Code...
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was reading yesterday on the ExpandoObject introduced in .NET 4.0, with this object type you could dynamically create the object at run-time and pass the object through to the other namespace.

This is not a perfect solution as there may be performance issues (I can't believe that Expando objects are as fast as static objects). There is also no compile (or run) time checking to ensure that all the fields are added.

Dynamic/ExpandoObject also supports adding methods to the object.

But, here is some sample source:

```
    void Method1()
    {


        var tableVars = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

        dynamic sampleObject = new ExpandoObject();
        sampleObject.Name = "Count";
        sampleObject.Type = "Int32";
        sampleObject.Value = "4";
        sampleObject.Default = "0";

        tableVars.Add("Sample", sampleObject);

        Insert("TableName", tableVars, "Connection");


    }

    string Insert(string table, Dictionary<string, dynamic> tableVars, string connection)
    {

        foreach (var v in tableVars)
        {
            Console.Write("Name is: ");

            Console.WriteLine(v.Value.Name);

        }

        return "";
    }
```

Depending on your situation, it may be better to do as @Benny indicated in his answer, but I wanted to introduce elements of the DLR as an option

Comment: Not that it couldn't be found with a simple google search, but here is a link to the Microsoft ExpandoObject page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Move all the common types (tableObject in this case) to a 3rd dll and reference him from both higher assemblies

Comment: A simpler answer in this case MAY be to move the definition of tableObject to the MyDLL assembly

Comment: Is this really the only way? To move it? There is no way to pass the custom object?

Comment: Well ... not really. You cetainly could pass it as object and use reflection to access the data. But that doesn't make much sense. It is the same with the "build-in" types. The only reason both of your assemblies know the string type is because both reference the System namespace/assembly. 

If you want to use your assembly in another application later on, you would have to define the type again. And what would happen if AppA defines it differently than AppB? How is MyDLL supposed to handle the object?